# How to stop all processes that prevent sleep via Terminal?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, power-management

In the Activity Manager, you can see which processes prevent the system from sleeping. I know that the `WindowsServer` is a false positive, but others are not.

Sometimes I attempt to put my MacBook to sleep, put it in the bag and it nearly overheats and drains battery, because a process in the background would prevent it from sleeping.

In particular I'm talking about `SpringBoard` which triggered me to ask for help. It was running, although the iOS Simulator wasn't even running anymore, [a long known issue that Apple doesn't seem to acknowledge](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/92951).

To help myself out of this situation, I just want to automatically kill those processes. I already have a solution to turn off Wifi and Bluetooth when sleeping via bash script and I wish to extend it by some code that will detect processes that prevent sleeping.

Right now I couldn't kill `SpringBoard`, because it was relaunched by its parent process `launchd_sim`. For some reason that process survived despite Xcode and the Simulator not running anymore.

Now, I have put `osascript -e 'quit app "launchd_sim"'` in my sleep script and the Mac will sleep again, but this is simple band-aid.

I need something robust. If I can't automate killing *any processes that block sleep*, having any visual sign of my Mac being unable to sleep before I leave it at least would be helpful. `WindowServer` and `bluetoothd` are exceptions to the rule as the `WindowServer` will not actually prevent sleep and bluetooth will be disabled from me as well.

I don't want any other future processes to cause me to experience this again, it's probably not very healthy for the device.

I know about `pmset -g assertions` and it printed:

```
   BackgroundTask                 0                                                                                           │
   ApplePushServiceTask           0                                                                                           │Name          Value
   UserIsActive                   1                                                                                           │------------- ------------------------------------
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0                                                                                           │ID            8
   PreventSystemSleep             0                                                                                           │Description   gitea home
   ExternalMedia                  0                                                                                           │Status        Pending
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1                                                                                           │Entered       2023-08-18 19:02:30 (3h)
   NetworkClientActive            0
```

before and after killing `launchd_sim` / `SpringBoard`. Below that I would get a list of PIDs and there was `SpringBoard`, not anymore. I could probably parse this, but maybe there is something that is way simpler? Can't I tell the Mac to sleep no matter what? I don't want it to decide for me and I think this is rather annoying.

Update: Today I also had to get rid of `apsd` and their address book sync service. Both processes drained 25% of my battery, my MBP was in my bag and it was very hot when I pulled it out. What the hell Apple, this is a joke. I don't even use FaceTime or the Address Book. I wish there was a way to just force sleep no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I came up with these three `alias`es that should at least help me to prevent this situation, hopefully:

```sh
alias cansleep="test ! $(pmset -g assertions | grep SystemSleep | grep -v 0)"
alias sleepnow="pmset sleepnow"
alias gosleep="cansleep && sleepnow || open -a 'Activity Monitor' && test"
```

Instead of simply closing the lid, I will run `gosleep` in the terminal. It should complain if there is a process preventing sleep.

Unfortunately, the MacBook might start sleeping with a delay anyways, which is still a time window in which a process that prevents system sleep could be started, but it's an improvement.

Since my goal is to prevent this from happening altogether, I don't consider my answer a very good answer, but it's the closest to prevent the issue I could come up with (so far).